# Tensorflow : Restoring a tensorflow model and pass a single image to examine gradients

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to restore a checkpoint and pass a single image and do guided backpropogation.

This is the code I'm using right now.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
from matplotlib import pylab as P
import pickle
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from net import network

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None ,1, 418400,3))

    sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('flat-3000.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./checkpoint'))

    logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Logits/Squeeze:0')
    neuron_selector = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    y = logits[0][neuron_selector]
    prediction = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
im = (((cv2.imread('./images/\Image_ALL_11.png', 1)) / 255) * 2 )- 1
im_flat = np.reshape(im, (1,418400,3), order = 'F')
prediction_class = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict = {images: [im_flat]})[0]
```

This is the error stack trace.

---

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1322     try:
-> 1323       return fn(*args)
   1324     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1301                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1302                                    status, run_metadata)
   1303 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input/Input' with dtype float and shape [?,1,418400,3]
     [[Node: Input/Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,418400,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: ArgMax/_121 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_292_ArgMax", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9df4a7dc7f9b> in <module>()
----> 1 prediction_class = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict = {images: [im_flat]})[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1119       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1121     else:
   1122       results = []

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1315     if handle is None:
   1316       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1317                            options, run_metadata)
   1318     else:
   1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1334         except KeyError:
   1335           pass
-> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1337 
   1338   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input/Input' with dtype float and shape [?,1,418400,3]
     [[Node: Input/Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,418400,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: ArgMax/_121 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_292_ArgMax", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Input/Input', defined at:
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 112, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1431, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 102, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-1fc4f0d15c89>", line 7, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('flat-3000.meta')
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1810, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input/Input' with dtype float and shape [?,1,418400,3]
     [[Node: Input/Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,418400,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: ArgMax/_121 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_292_ArgMax", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I'm using tensorflow v1.4.1.
The error traces of tensorflow is very confusing, so I don't understand why the error says that I don't feed anything to the Input place holder.

This is the network I'm using.

```
class network():

    def __init__(self):
        self.initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        self.isTrain = True
        self.epochs = 100
        self.batch_size = 10
        self.data_size = 2503
        self.restore = False
        self.decay = 0.99
        self.model_name = 'model'
        self.ckpt_dir = './' + self.model_name + "/checkpoint"
        self.val_fraction = 0.1
        self.test_fraction = 0.1
        self.drop = 0.5


    def layer(self, input_, output_ch, kernel, stride, drop_rate, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer"):

        with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:

            x = Conv(input_, output_ch, self.initializer, kernel = kernel, stride = stride, name = 'Conv', pad = "VALID")
            x = batchnorm(x, isTrain = self.isTrain, decay = self.decay)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
            x = dropout(x, rate = drop_rate, training = self.isTrain)

        return x

    def model(self):

        if not os.path.exists(self.model_name):
            os.mkdir(self.model_name)

        with tf.variable_scope('Input') as scope:   
            self.input_ = tf.placeholder(name = "Input", shape = [None, 1, 418400, 3], dtype = tf.float32)
            self.labels = tf.placeholder(name = "Labels", shape = [None, 5], dtype = tf.float32)
            self.isTrain = tf.placeholder(name = "isTrain", shape = None, dtype = tf.bool)
            self.step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
            self.lr = tf.placeholder(name = "LR", shape = None, dtype = tf.float32)

        print('Output Shapes:')
        x = self.layer(self.input_, output_ch = 64, kernel = (1,50), stride = 15, drop_rate = self.drop, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer_1")
        print('Layer_1:',x.get_shape())

        x = self.layer(x, output_ch = 128, kernel = (1,50), stride = 10, drop_rate = self.drop, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer_2")
        print('Layer_2:',x.get_shape())

        x = self.layer(x, output_ch = 256, kernel = (1,10), stride = 5, drop_rate = self.drop, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer_3")
        print('Layer_3:',x.get_shape())

        x = self.layer(x, output_ch = 512, kernel = (1,10), stride = 5, drop_rate = self.drop, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer_4")
        print('Layer_4:',x.get_shape())

        x = self.layer(x, output_ch = 5, kernel = (1,10), stride = 5, drop_rate = self.drop, pad = "VALID", name = "Layer_5")
        print('Layer_5:',x.get_shape())

        x = AvgPool(x, kernel = (1,21), stride = 1, name = "AvgPool_1", pad = 'VALID')
        print('AvgPool_1:',x.get_shape())

        with tf.variable_scope("Logits") as scope:
            self.logits = tf.squeeze(x, [1,2], name = "Squeeze")
            self.logits = tf.nn.tanh(self.logits)
            print('Logits:',self.logits.get_shape())

        with tf.variable_scope("Loss") as scope:

            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = self.logits, labels = self.labels))

        with tf.variable_scope("Accuracy") as scope:

            self.logits_max_args = tf.argmax(self.logits, axis = 1)
            self.labels_max_args = tf.argmax(self.labels, axis = 1)
            self.equal = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(self.logits_max_args, self.labels_max_args), tf.float32))
            self.batch_acc = tf.divide(self.equal, tf.cast(tf.shape(self.logits)[0], tf.float32))

        with tf.variable_scope("Optimizer") as scope:

            update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
            with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
                self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss, self.step)
            self.saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 3)

        with tf.variable_scope("Summary") as scope:

            loss_sum = tf.summary.scalar('Loss', self.loss)
            acc_sum = tf.summary.scalar('Batch Accuracy', self.batch_acc)
            self.summary = tf.summary.merge([loss_sum, acc_sum])
```

Comment: hello, can anybody help me ?

Comment: The shape of im_flat seems wrong, TF expects you to give it [?,1,418400,3], and you are giving it [1,418400,3]. The ? dimension allows you to train with multiple data points in a single go. You could just put your existing instance in a singleton list to fix this issue.

Comment: nvm.. you are already doing that. Is the contents of im in the float format?

Comment: but feeding it using 'feed_dict' should solve the issue right ? I guess the error trace is saying that 'Input/Input' is not getting the data fed to it. Do you want me to add the network structure python code for more clarity ?

Comment: Yes the contents of im_flat are float. Actually I'm reading a RGB image and flattening it, before feeding it to the model.

Comment: You are making up for the ? dimension by putting im_flat in a python list. Maybe tensorflow can't figure out of the shape of the input if part of the shape comes from a python list and the rest of it comes from some numpy array.. Maybe make a numpy array of shape (1, 1,418400,3) and give it that instead.

Comment: How to do you feed that array into TF ? If I use feed dict it would make the dimension (1,1,1,418400,3)

Comment: The error clearly seems to be about you giving it the data in the wrong shape. You could try removing the [ and ] in the feed_dict invocation (just give it the image directly and also try giving it the image in a np array of shape [1,1,418400,3].. You are currently giving it the image in a singleton python list.. I suspect it doesn't know what to do with that.

Comment: I am still getting same error, after doing all the suggestions.